# [RPi3][Bluez] Managed to connect to a BLE device but can't list GATT attributes

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, characteristics

I am doing a project where I need to create communication between two Raspberry Pi 3 on stretch (RPi) wirelessly with callback functionalities using C++ code. The first is supposed to send data to the second one.  I decided to create a bluetooth connexion between the two using the on-board bluetooth-chips.

So first I decided to compile Linux Bluetooth Stack: Bluez on both RPi from source, version 5.50. Following this tutorial : https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation on Adafruit. I managed to send a message from one pi to another using these codes :https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html. But to read a message sent by the client, I have to call the function "read(client, buf, sizeof(buf))" as shown in the server code which is a bit restrictive. I want to be notified whenever a message is received so that a callback function can be called. I saw it could be done by enabling notifications on the GATT Characteristics used for the communication.

This level of specification is not really shown on the C++ codes I got from https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html. After having improved my knowledge on GATT with this : https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/ , I decided to follow Tony D's youtube tutorial on how to use Bluez APi 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fQR2PHMDWE.

To make it easier, I decided to left one RPi aside and tried to connect a Bluetooth audio headset JBL T450BT which use Bluetooth 4.0, so it is supposed to support Bluetooth Low Energy.

On bluetoothctl here's the problem, I manage to power on the controller, scan on and detect the headset. I then trust, pair and connect. In GATT menu, I enter the command : list-attributes [dev address]. Bluetoothctl prints no error but returns nothing and is ready to receive other command lines.

```
sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# show
Controller XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (public)
Name: VoitureRPi
Alias: VoitureRPi
Class: 0x004c0000
Powered: yes
Discoverable: no
Pairable: yes
UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# scan on
Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C JBL T450BT
[bluetooth]# trust 78:44:05:BC:12:0C 
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C Trusted: yes
Changing 78:44:05:BC:12:0C trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 78:44:05:BC:12:0C 
Attempting to pair with 78:44:05:BC:12:0C
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 78:44:05:BC:12:0C 
Attempting to connect to 78:44:05:BC:12:0C
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 78:44:05:BC:12:0C ServicesResolved: yes
[JBL T450BT]# menu gatt
[JBL T450BT]# list-attributes 78:44:05:BC:12:0C 
[JBL T450BT]#
```

From there I get no answer from bluetoothctl but no error as well, as I told you. I am not able to discover services/characteristics. 
On the youtube tuto I followed,it was told that the GATT services and Characteristics discovery was done during the pairing/first connexion. I assume that the Pi intends to do it but fails. That's maybe why I get the sequence :
connected: yes, ServicesResolved: yes Paired successfully and then  ServicesResolved: no, connected no. Nothing like : [NEW] XXX Service or Characteristcs is shown.
I don't think the problem comes from the headset because it does the same thing on other devices I connect to. I have both pulseaudio and bluealsa packages installed on the RPi.

As mentionned in this tuto

Here the bluetooth status :

```
systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-11-08 11:29:38 CET; 27min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 2646 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
     └─2646 /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental
```

Here's what hciconfig gives :

```
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
BD Address: B8:27:EB:A8:0C:20  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
UP RUNNING 
RX bytes:11205 acl:76 sco:0 events:520 errors:0
TX bytes:219869 acl:433 sco:0 commands:150 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Name: 'VoitureRPi'
Class: 0x4c0000
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Telephony
Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x168
LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2209
Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

Here's also what the D-Bus introspection tool returns :

```
busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
     └─/org/bluez/hci0
        └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_78_44_05_BC_12_0C
          ├─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_78_44_05_BC_12_0C/fd1
          └─/org/bluez/hci0/dev_78_44_05_BC_12_0C/player0
```

For people who got problems with pairing and connecting, this source was a huge help :https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/bluetooth_02_en.html

Anyway so that's my problem. I want to access Characteristics and their UUID's to be able to modify their permission or to create a new service with its own characteristics suited to my project. 
To this point I think this is the only way to implement a notifier with a callback in a bluetooth communication. Maybe I'm wrong. Do you have any clue whatsoever ? :)

Comment: Do you have the btmon tool on your Raspberry Pi? If you do, run it in the background and see the output messages. btmon gives you a lot more debugging messages and you can understand what's happening through it. Also, try setting your io capabilities to Display/Keyboard, just in case the pairing is failing because of that. You can do this by running "btmgmt io-cap 4", and then starting bluetoothctl with "bluetoothctl --agent KeyboardDisplay".

Comment: Alright, I am going to see what it gives me ! Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I have the btmon tool. Does it come with Bluez ? Or do i have to download it and compile it ?

Comment: Usually it comes with BlueZ, but if you don't have it on your Pi then you'll need to cross compile it and transfer it over, or search for a btmon binary that has already been compiled for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: did you find a solution with the empty attribute list? I'm struggeling with the same problem on my rp2. It already worked and now it is broken  and I try to fix this issue :(. Pairing and connecting still works.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. In my case I was not running the `bluetoothd` with the `--experimental` option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A.Baur, the "--experimental" option was the last missing thing.
My system:Debian 10 + KDE
Installed:
 - bluez-*
 
 - bluetooth
 
 - pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

Steps:
1. stop bluetooth service: `>sudo systemctl stop bluetooth`
2. modify: /etc/init.d/bluetooth ; by adding to the line:

```
SSD_OPTIONS="**--experimental** --oknodo --quiet --exec $DAEMON -- $NOPLUGIN_OPTION"
```

3. start bluetooth service: `>sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
4. connect to Bose QC35 II by `bluetoothctl` or other GUI tool.

Comment: is `--experimental` meant to be surrounded with `**`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in RPi with python examples of advertisement and gatt server from bluez-5.50. I used nRF tool to test it.